# Unix shell error after encrypting a script file

Tags: shell, unix, openssl

I have 2 shell scripts - one calling another script.
callouter.sh, callscript.sh.

callouter.sh :

```
export oraSchemaPass='scott/tiger'
echo 'This script is about to run another script'
sh ./callscript.sh
```

callscript.sh :

```
sqlplus -S ${oraSchemaPass} @/home/scripts/callscript.sql
```

callscript.sql is :

```
set pagesize 1000
select * from emp;
EXIT
```

This works perfectly fine. No error whatsoever. This is korn shell by the way.

Now I did 2 things :

1. encrypted the callouter.sh using openssl :

   ```
   openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -a -in /home/scripts/callouter.sh -out /home/scripts/callouter.enc -pass pass:W3lc0m3987
   ```

The file encrypted successfully.

2. Replaced the callouter.sh content with :

   ```
   eval $( /home/scripts/decrypt.sh /home/scripts/callouter.enc )
   ```

Content of decrypt.sh is :

```
openssl enc -d -e -aes-256-cbc -a -in $1 -pass pass:W3lc0m3987
```

Now when I run callouter.sh I get the below error :

```
./callouter.sh: Line 1: export: `This script is about to run another script': not a valid identifier
./callouter.sh: Line 1: export: `./callscript.sh': not a valid identifier
```

Can anyone help me with how to resolve the error? I searched the error on net and it has got to do with invalid variables and improper uses of inverted quotes. I double checked my scripts and I got no such mistakes. I am starting to think the encrypted file is causing this.

Edit : purpose is to hide the password of Oracle schema. Yes for the purpose of the question I used the decrypt.sh. In the environment decrypt.sh will be accessed only by the user calling the scripts. And for that we have set up an environment variable SEC_DIR which will be the home directory of each user. So for example user 'A' will have SEC_DIR as /home/A/dev/sec_dir. Inside this decrypt.sh will be placed.

Comment: Apparently the result of `eval $( /home/scripts/decrypt.sh /home/scripts/callouter.enc )` is like putting all your script's code into a single line. What's the purpose of this encryption? Hiding the hard-coded password in `callouter.sh` by using a hard-coded password in `decrypt.sh`? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: Edited the question as suggested.

Comment: Why don't you restrict the access to the script `callouter.sh` to the user who is allowed to acess the database in the same way as you plan to do for the `decrypt.sh` script? Or add the login to `callscript.sql` script and restrict the access to `callscript.sql` in a similar way?

Comment: We are doing that too. But few Project Managers also do not want Oracle schema username n password as it's not SOX compliant. So we are doing this to comply with such policies.

Comment: Please add all clarification or requested information to the question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: I have added all the script lines, the shell being used (k-shell), the way the respective scripts are being called, the encrypt command and decrypt files being used. Not sure what else I can share. The description contains every scripts being used. Even the error too. I'm not sure what else I can share. Do You have anything particular information in mind?

Comment: All information you provided in in comments should be part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general I do *not* recommend your approach** of hiding a password by encrypting it using a second password. This does not add any real protection, only a bit more work to get the password.

In any case, everyone who can read both the encrypted data and the script `decrypt.sh` with its embedded decryption password can get the cleartext data.

Anyway, here is a possible solution:

**1.** Instead of encrypting a script with embedded login data I suggest to encrypt a file that contains only the login data as text.

**Example:**

`login.txt`

```
scott/tiger
```

Encrypt in the same way:

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -a -in login.txt -out login.enc -pass pass:W3lc0m3987
```

Use the decryption in your script `callscript.sh`, e.g.

```
sqlplus -S "$( /home/scripts/decrypt.sh login.enc )" @/home/scripts/callscript.sql
```

---

**2.** Another option based on your approach might be

```
/home/scripts/decrypt.sh /home/scripts/callouter.enc | /bin/bash
```

(Replace `/bin/bash` with the shell you want to use.)

---

The error `` export: `something': not a valid identifier `` results from using `$( ... )` without quotes. Example:

```
$ printf "a\nb\nc\n"
a
b
c

$ echo x$(printf "a\nb\nc\n")y
xa b cy

$ echo x"$(printf "a\nb\nc\n")"y
xa
b
cy
```

**3.** This means you could also use

```
eval "$( /home/scripts/decrypt.sh /home/scripts/callouter.enc )"
```

---

From the 3 proposed solutions I recommend the solution 1 as the least evil. Solution 1 passes the output of your command as an argument to `sqlplus` while 2 and 3 execute the command's output by a shell which is a higher security risk.

Comment: The last code worked like a charm. Guess I should not have used eval in the new script I wrote. I thought I had eval pinned down. Damn! Gotta read upon eval now. But thanks for the solution. I have marked it as answer.

Comment: One burning question : Why is the script throwing "not a valid identifier" message when eval comes into picture?